# Mongoose mixed Type object array, can findOneAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

> I have a controller edit card which updates the fields of cardsArray object.
> cardsArray is mixed type object as fileds of each card object is different so i am storing mixed.type
> Althought pushing new card using addCard controller works perfectly
> But when edit card controller is called, it gives type error
> When edit Controlller is callled is gives following error:
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'cardsArray')

```
    // Schema
     const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
              {
                name: {
                  type: String,
                  required: true,
                },
                email: {
                  type: String,
                  required: true,
                },
                password: {
                  type: String,
                  required: true,
                },
            
                cardsArray: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed }],
              }
```

);

```
    //__Mongodb Data
    
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "63b43ab32fc8d3c100cafecc"
          },
          "name": "usern_name",
          "email": "pr****@gmail.com",
          "password": "$2b$12$3nwifHakrBu94BwLXAC4Nu16Kw0.xyW8vAIPTMSgY7cYttVklDIZq",
          "cardsArray": [
            {
              "title": "some_title",
              "category": "Bank",
              "cardHolder": "some_name",
              "cardNumber": "54545454",
              "expiry": "23/01",
              "cvv": "***",
              "logoIndex": 72,
              "isFavourite": false,
              "_id": {
                "$oid": "63b83cc77288d277ef359533"
              }
            }
          ],
          
          "loginIdsArray": [],
          "docsArray": [],
          "activitiesArray": [],
          "__v": 0
        }
    
    
    // Add Card Controller.js___
    
         addCard: async (req, res) => {
            console.log(req.body.data, req.body.user_id)
            // console.log('obj_id', newObjectId)
            req.body.data._id = newObjectId;
            try {
        
              const response = await UserDatabase.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: req.body.user_id },
                {
                  $push: {
                    // cardsArray: req.body.data,
                    cardsArray: { $each: [req.body.data] },
                  },
                },
                { returnOriginal: false }
              );
              res.status(200).send(response);
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
              res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
            }
          },
        
    // edit card controller.js 
 
editCard: async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  const { category, title, cardHolder, cardNumber, expiry, cvv, logoIndex, isFavourite } = req.body;
  console.log(req.params.id)

  try {
 

    const response = await UserDatabase.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: "63b43ab32fc8d3c100cafecc", 'cardsArray._id': "63b709fc69a1cfa6fccd645c" },
      {
        $set: {
          "cardsArray.$.title": req.body.title,
          "cardsArray.$.category": req.body.category,
          "cardsArray.$.cardHolder": req.body.cardHolder,
          "cardsArray.$.cardNumber": req.body.cardNumber,
          "cardsArray.$.expiry": req.body.expiry,
          "cardsArray.$.cvv": req.body.cvv,
          "cardsArray.$.logoIndex": req.body.logoIndex,
          "cardsArray.$.isFavourite": req.body.isFavourite
        }
      },
    );

    console.log(response)
    res.status(201).json(response.cardsArray);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it means that there is no data matching the following _id and cardsArray._id
i thinks so its fails to find the feild 'cardsArray._id',first try finding the value by just findOne

```
await UserDatabase.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "63b43ab32fc8d3c100cafecc", 'cardsArray._id': "63b709fc69a1cfa6fccd645c" })
```

if your find doesn't work try below methord not sure but it may work you have to either find the id and loop through the cardsArray of use $in or $match

```
 await UserDatabase.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "63b43ab32fc8d3c100cafecc", 'cardsArray':{$in:[ {_id:"63b709fc69a1cfa6fccd645c" }]})
```